# Is there any way to create NPM package without disrupting the Next.js 14 folder structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, npm-package, npm-publish

Is there any way to create NPM package without disrupting the Next.js 14 folder structure.
I am going create NPM package that uses Next.js 14 and their folder structure.
I have installed using **npx create-next-app@latest**.

I created NPM package using **npm link** and imported in another Next.js project but it didn't work for me. I am finding solution that uses Next.js bundler and configuration to export modules or whole folder.

Comment: I'm not really sure how/why you'd use a NextJS project as a library. NextJS is a framework for creating a SPA. What is your actual use-case?

Comment: I am going to make a full-fledged backend as a service in Next.js and I also want it to integrate into Next.js/React.js apps like WordPress when someone enters URL /wp-admin they will enter into the admin.